# What order do Netfilter hooks go in, if they all specify NF_IP_PRI_LAST or NF_IP_PRI_FIRST?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, netfilter

If I write a few kernel modules, and in all of them specify they should be the first (or last) netfilter hook called, in what order will they actually be called?

```
netfilter_ops_out.hook     = hook_func_out;
netfilter_ops_out.pf       = PF_INET;
netfilter_ops_out.hooknum  = NF_IP_LOCAL_OUT;
netfilter_ops_out.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;

ret = nf_register_hook(&netfilter_ops_out);
if (0 > ret) {
    printk("Error registering netfilter hook: %d\n", ret);
    return ret;
}    

netfilter_ops_in.hook      = hook_func_in;
netfilter_ops_in.pf        = PF_INET;
netfilter_ops_in.hooknum   = NF_IP_LOCAL_IN;
netfilter_ops_in.priority  = NF_IP_PRI_LAST;

ret = nf_register_hook(&netfilter_ops_in);
if (0 > ret) {
    printk("Error registering netfilter hook: %d\n", ret);
    return ret;
}
```

Experimentally, I made two modules, `insmod`ed them in the two different orders - but they gave the same result, implying there's some suborder that's not just 'first come first serve'.  (It's also not alphabetical...)

Comment: `nf_register_hook()` is called in the `module_init` function.  An older kernel: 2.6.18.  One module modifies a packet, the other logs it, both use the same registering code (above).  But no matter what order I load the modules in, I always see the packet as modified in the logger.  I figured somehow I ought to be able to make the logger run before the modifier... but no dice.

Comment: Sorry, my explanation just wound up confusing the issue further.  I do have four hooks, 2 of each LOCAL_IN and LOCAL_OUT.  The two modules both hook on the incoming and outgoing, but I'm only focusing on the incoming.

Answer (score 5):

From the nf_register_hook() codes, we can know that if two hooks belong to the same nf_hooks[reg->pf][reg->hooknum], the hook execute sequence is decided by priority. If the priority is also the same, the sequence is 'first come first serve'. See following codes:

```
int nf_register_hook(struct nf_hook_ops *reg)
{
    struct nf_hook_ops *elem;
    int err;

    err = mutex_lock_interruptible(&nf_hook_mutex);
    if (err < 0)
        return err;
    list_for_each_entry(elem, &nf_hooks[reg->pf][reg->hooknum], list) {
        if (reg->priority < elem->priority)
            break;
    }
    list_add_rcu(&reg->list, elem->list.prev);
    mutex_unlock(&nf_hook_mutex);
#if defined(CONFIG_JUMP_LABEL)
    static_key_slow_inc(&nf_hooks_needed[reg->pf][reg->hooknum]);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```